# Matching text to images using fuzzy search

Tags: search, levenshtein-distance

I am using this package: https://github.com/blevesearch/bleve to create a mapping of products2images.

It is working fine when I use single terms, but not at all if I use an entire phrase. For instance, if I use this :

```
    query := bleve.NewFuzzyQuery("lacteo")
```

it will correctly map the right image. However, If I do this :

```
    query := bleve.NewFuzzyQuery("lacteo leche yogurt cebolla")
```

It will not match anything at all.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Set DB :

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/blevesearch/bleve"
)

func main() {
    message := []struct {
        Id   string
        Body string
    }{
        {
            Id:   "lacteos.jpg",
            Body: "lacteo leche yogurt cebolla",
        },
        {
            Id:   "cafe.jpg",
            Body: "café yerba té",
        },
        {
            Id:   "queso.jpg",
            Body: "lacteo leche yogurt cebolla queso",
        },
        {
            Id:   "harina.jpg",
            Body: "harina",
        },
    }
    mapping := bleve.NewIndexMapping()
    index, err := bleve.New("example.bleve", mapping)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    index.Index(message[0].Id, message[0])
    index.Index(message[1].Id, message[1])
    index.Index(message[2].Id, message[2])
    index.Index(message[3].Id, message[3])
}
```

Search for something :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/blevesearch/bleve"
)

func main() {
    index, _ := bleve.Open("example.bleve")
    query := bleve.NewFuzzyQuery("lacteo leche yogurt cebolla queso")
    query.SetFuzziness(2)
    searchRequest := bleve.NewSearchRequest(query)
    searchResult, err := index.Search(searchRequest)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    for _, v := range searchResult.Hits {
        fmt.Println(v.ID)
        fmt.Println(v.Score)
        fmt.Println("-------------")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after posting an issue at their repo : https://github.com/blevesearch/bleve/issues/1565 I found out this is actually not supported. I ended up adding a little bit more logic to my side to make this work.